# bash getting background process id gives parent pid

Tags: bash, pid

Creating a bash script with this command:

```
cat <<"END"> z
#! /bin/bash

sleep 20 && exit 1 &
ret=$!

ps $ret | grep $ret
END
```

and then running it gives:

```
7230 pts/39   S+     0:00 /bin/bash ./z
```

I was expecting to see `sleep 20 ...` which is the child process. If I remove the `&& exit 1` it does return the child process.

Whats the reason? How can I get the child process id in above statement?

Comment: I think the command is displayed with the name of the parent process because the command is more complex and a name could not be generated.

Comment: @dan1st well ... that does not make sense to me. Regardless of ps $ret | grep $ret I actually checked the return pid and compared with the parent and child pid. It actually returns the parent pid

Comment: `man bash` says that `AND and OR lists are sequences of one or more pipelines separated by the && and || control operators, respectively.` I can't see what that implies with respect to your question, but we can agree that it won't be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already get the right information about the child process. Only in your case, `ps` doesn't know or want to show a proper `COMMAND` name for your chained sub-process you start in the background - what probably confused you.

Looks like this is the case with the chained commands (`.. && ...`, thus it has nothing to do with `exit 1` could be also `echo 5` etc.) where the [*process group leader*](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-10.html) name is showed as `cmd` name instead.

From the ([ps man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html))

```sh
`cmd | COMMAND`: simple name of executable

# Process state codes
`S`: interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
`+`: is in the foreground process group
```

See the `S+` in your `ps | grep` output.

So, you can adapt your script a bit to confirm that you actually capture(d) the right information about the child process, like so:

```sh
cat <<"END"> z
#! /bin/bash

sleep 20 && exit 1 &
ret=$!

echo $ret

jobs -l

# display parent and child process info
# -j Jobs format
ps -j  $$ $ret 
END
```

Output of `echo $ret`:

```
30274
```

Output of `jobs -l`:

```sh
[1]+ 30274 Running                 sleep 20 && exit 1 &
```

Output of `ps -j  $$ $ret`:

```sh
PID   PGID   SID   TTY    STAT    TIME COMMAND
30273 30273 21804 pts/0    S+     0:00 /bin/bash ./z
30274 30273 21804 pts/0    S+     0:00 /bin/bash ./z
```

Note that both the parent and child have the same `PGID`, whereas the pid **30274** of the child process displayed by `jobs -l` and `ps ...`  matches.

Further, if you change `sleep 20 && exit 1 &` as `bash -c 'sleep 20 && exit 1' &` you would get a proper command name for the child this time, as follows (cf. output order above):

```sh
30384

[1]+ 30384 Running                 bash -c 'sleep 20 && exit 1' &

PID    PGID  SID   TTY    STAT    TIME COMMAND
30383 30383 21804 pts/0    S+     0:00 /bin/bash ./z
30384 30383 21804 pts/0    S+     0:00 bash -c sleep 20 && exit 1
```

Last but not least, in your original version instead of `ps $ret | grep $ret` you could also try

```sh
pstree -s $ret
```

From [pstree man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pstree.1.html)

> -s:     Show parent processes of the specified process.

Which will provide you with an output similar to that one below, which would also confirm that you get the right process info for `sleep 20 && exit 1 &`:

```sh
systemd───systemd───gnome-terminal-───bash───bash───sleep
```

Answer (score 1):

What you see is not parent pid, but sub-shell pid

When you run :

```
sleep 20 && exit 1 &
```

The processes tree is like :

```
current-shell ---> sub-shell ---> 'sleep 20 && exit 1'
```

When you run :

```
sleep 20 &
```

The processes tree is like :

```
current-shell ---> 'sleep 20'
```

Reason why you see pid for 'sleep 20'

Comment: thanks for your answer. It was very helpful. I decided to pick the other answer which was more complete

Answer (score 1):

> Whats the reason?

The reason is that some entity has to do `&&`. It can't be `sleep`, because `sleep` only sleeps, and after `sleep` terminates (so there is no longer `sleep` to make any decision), some "entity" needs to compare the exit status of `sleep` and decide and then execute `exit 1`. That "entity" is the shell, that has to be "above" `sleep` to do the action. So the "real" background process is the shell, and `sleep` is it's child process.

In case of only `sleep 20 &` there is an optimization in bash that the parent shell in case bash sees there is only a single command to do. So bash scans the whole `command command bla bla &` and sees there is only one command to do. Because of that bash does only call to `exec` instead of the standard `fork+exec` and becomes `sleep` itself instead of running a child process. Because of the `exec` the subshell becomes `sleep`, so you see it in process name. It's a resource optimization done bash.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It was very helpful. I decided to pick the other answer which was more complete